# $.ajax not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have the following code that is working on Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE9

```
$.ajax({
  type : type,
  url : url,
  data : reqData,
  crossDomain: true,
  cache: false,
  dataType : dataType,
  contentType : contentType,
  success : successFunction
}).fail(function() {
  showError("IE9!");
});
```

type is POST, dataType is JSON and contentType is application/json
All the other parameters are correct

I've tried removing the contentType, removing the cache, setting cache to true, nothing seems to work

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the error given? Does the ajax call reach the server at all?

Comment: Can you provide any more information about the request? If it is `crossDomain`, does the server have CORS support established, including responding to [pre-flight `OPTIONS` requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) the browser can send? jQuery's `error` (and `.fail()`) callbacks include an `errorThrown` argument -- what does it tell you? And, try to capture the **Network** details in IE9's dev tools; check the status and response of the requests that are sent and compare to what you expect.

Comment: Have you tried using an http debugging tool like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) or the network tab in the browser's debug tools? Those tools will help you see the traffic so you know if the request is actually being sent, what the return code is, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use normal ajax for cross domain access in ie, you have to use XDR for this purpose
please refer [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd573303%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check the url path ( should be absolute ) and make it unique adding a timestamp for example

```
var url = 'http://mydomain.com/'   ** not '/' **
var timestamp = new Date()
var uniqueUrl = url + (uri.indexOf("?") > 0 ? "&" : "?") + "timestamp=" + timestamp.getTime()
```

then

```
url : uniqueUrl,
```